# Run 2 UIs on diffrent monitor using qt-creator on Dual-Head Graphics Card

Tags: linux, qt, qt-creator, multiple-monitors

I have a Dual-Display Graphics card, on my system (RHEL 6.3).

I have developed one simple application using qt creator (qt-4.8), which throws two different UIs.

When I execute this then both UIs starts in only one display.

What I need is my one UI should run on primary screen and one on secondary screen (i.e. 0.0 and 0.1).

How should I do this using qt-creator?

```
xclock -display :0.0 
xclock -display :0.1
```

works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tejas,

To display your Second UI on Secondary Monitor you can use setParent property for your Second UI as :

int screenNumber = 1;       /* Desired screen no */

QWidget secondaryUI_widget;   /* Secondary UI Object which is to be displayed on secondary monitor */

QDesktopWidget myDesktopWidget;   /* Create an object of QDesktopWidget */

secondUI_myDesktopWidget.setParent(myDesktopWidget(screenNumber));

The above line will set the desired screen on which you would like to display your page as parent for your UI object.
Now you can call show() function for your second UI anywhere in your program , the second UI will be displayed on desired screen number as being by screenNumber value

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [QDesktopWidget](http://doc.qt.digia.com/stable/qdesktopwidget.html) to get screen information. It Allows you to query the amount of screens and the dimension of each one with

```
int QDesktopWidget::screenCount () const;
const QRect QDesktopWidget::availableGeometry ( int screen = -1 ) const;
```

From there, you can move your widget to any given screen. For instance, the following code  move the widget to a given screen or to the default one if the specified screen is not available:

```
QDesktopWidget* w = QApplication::desktop();
//some value
int mydesiredscreen = 1;
//fallback to default screen if none
if(mydesiredscreen >=  w->screenCount())  mydesiredscreen = -1; 

QRect rect1 = w->availableGeometry(mydesiredscreen);
mywindow->move(rect1.topLeft());
```